# Check if table contains <tr> elements

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a test that tests search functionality of a table. It takes a first row in table, gets some data out of the row and then inputs the data into search box. It then searches the table again and then checks the data from search result if they match the data that was in the table before the search.

The problem is that if no data is found the table has no  elements. My test code throws a timeout exception on this part of code:

```
//Get search results
var resultRows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
//If there are not results, search is not functional
if (resultRows != null && resultRows.Count > 0)
{
    //Iterate through search results
    foreach (var row in resultRows)
    {
        //Get columns for current row
        var resultCols = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        //If column 'Priceable item' value is different than original data, search is not functional
        if (resultCols[searchColumn].Text != searchData)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    isValid = false;
}

return isValid;
```

The exception is thrown once i reach this line in debugger:

```
var resultRows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

How could I check if table contains any elements by tag  before it finds all  elements?

Comment: What exception is thrown (edit the full exception into your question)? What value does `table` hold when that line throws? My guess is that `table` is null, etc. and that's why the exception is thrown. Post some more of the code before the exception... at least the part where `table` is assigned.

Comment: BTW, `resultRows` will never be `null` so you can remove that `null` check.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to find TR element in following manner

```
List<WebElement> resultRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr"));

//if your table has certain identifier/class
    //List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[class='CLASS_NAME']/tbody/tr"));


if (resultRows != null && resultRows.Count > 0)
{
    //Iterate through search results
    foreach (var row in resultRows)
    {
        //Get columns for current row
        var resultCols = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        //If column 'Priceable item' value is different than original data, search is not functional
        if (resultCols[searchColumn].Text != searchData)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    isValid = false;
}

return isValid;
```

Comment: You've changed the name of the variable from `resultRows` to `rows` so your code won't compile.